# Postgres query how to club date and time if time is not null

Tags: postgresql

```
with  data as(SELECT c."id",c."accountId",c."name",c."campaignType",c."status",
     (CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' IS NULL THEN csr."startDate"
     ELSE cast(cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' as TIMESTAMP)
     END) as "startDate",
    
CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' IS NOT NULL THEN NULL 
  ELSE csr."timeSlot"->>'type' END as "timeSlotType",
     
 (CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' IS not NULL THEN Null ELSE 
   --  CASE WHEN csr."timeSlotType"->>'startTime' IS NULL THEN NULL 
      CASE WHEN csr."timeSlot"->>'type'='MORNING' THEN '07:00'
       WHEN csr."timeSlot"->>'type'='AFTERNOON' THEN '12:00'
       WHEN csr."timeSlot"->>'type'='EVENING' THEN '17:00'
       WHEN csr."timeSlot"->>'type'='CUSTOM' THEN (csr."timeSlot"->>'startTime')::json->>'hour'||':'||((csr."timeSlot"->>'startTime')::json->>'minute')
     ELSE csr."timeSlot"->>'startTime' END END )::TIME as "startTime",
     
 split_part(cb."batchRunId", '-',6)::decimal as batchNumber,  
     'CAMPAIGN' as type
     
 FROM "Campaigns" c 
     LEFT JOIN "CampaignScheduleRequests" csr
     ON c."id"=csr."campaignId" 
     LEFT JOIN "CampaignBatches" cb 
     ON csr."id"=cb."requestId") 
 SELECT *  FROM data as d
     WHERE  d."status" IN ('ACTIVATED')
```

OUTPUT of the above query
[image: op]

Required o/p
Start time column should be concatenation of start date and startTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
with  data as(
    SELECT  c."id",
            c."accountId",
            c."name",
            c."campaignType",
            c."status",
            coalesce((cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt')::timestamp, 
                      csr."startDate")
            ) as "startDate",
            CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails" ? 'initiatedAt' THEN NULL 
                 ELSE csr."timeSlot"->>'type' 
            END as "timeSlotType",
            (CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails" ? 'initiatedAt' THEN NULL 
                  ELSE CASE csr."timeSlot"->>'type' 
                        WHEN 'MORNING'   THEN '07:00'
                        WHEN 'AFTERNOON' THEN '12:00'
                        WHEN 'EVENING'   THEN '17:00'
                        WHEN 'CUSTOM' THEN (csr."timeSlot"->'startTime')->>'hour'
                                           ||':'
                                           ||(csr."timeSlot"->'startTime')->>'minute'
                        ELSE csr."timeSlot"->>'startTime' --invalid format could cause problems with ::time
                       END 
             END )::TIME as "startTime",
            split_part(cb."batchRunId", '-',6)::decimal as batchNumber,  
            'CAMPAIGN' as type
    FROM "Campaigns" c 
     LEFT JOIN "CampaignScheduleRequests" csr ON c."id"=csr."campaignId" 
     LEFT JOIN "CampaignBatches"          cb  ON csr."id"=cb."requestId"
    WHERE  c."status" IN ('ACTIVATED')
) 
SELECT *,
       "startDate"+coalesce("startTime",'00:00'::time) as "newStartTimestamp"
FROM data;
```

1. Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to shorten the null replacements:

   ```sql
   CASE WHEN cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' IS NULL 
        THEN csr."startDate" 
        ELSE cast(cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt' as TIMESTAMP)
   END
   ```

   is the same as

   ```sql
   coalesce((cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt')::timestamp, csr."startDate")
   ```
2. In [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) you can do a single expression evaluation:

   ```sql
   CASE expression 
        WHEN value1 THEN... 
        WHEN value2 THEN...
   ```

   instead of a series of checks

   ```sql
   CASE 
        WHEN expression=value1 THEN... 
        WHEN expression=value2 THEN...
   ```
3. Instead of casting back to `json` after using the `->>` operator that gives you text: `(jsonb->>'key1')::json->>'key2'`, you can just use [`->` to keep `json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) output the first time.
4. [`?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) lets you check the presence of a key `json?'key1'` without having to check for null in an attempted read `json->>'key1' is null`.
5. You can add `time` to `date` or `timestamp` directly, the same how you'd add an `interval`. And to avoid nullifying your `intitiatedAt`-based `startDate` when adding a `null`-valued `startTime`, you can use `coalesce()` again  - which I think was your main question.

Comment: by above solution , customised date time is in IST and rest are coming in UTC how to return in UTC

Comment: I'd guess it'll be enough to cast it to time zone aware `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp` here (line 7): `(cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt')::timestamptz,`. [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rCJYk3mb33TGLXvYUzRVKo/0). Can you show some examples of what you get under `cb."executionDetails"->>'initiatedAt'`?

Comment: adding one image in description .. I want either in UTC OR IN ITC

Comment: @PJ It's best if you open a new question, reducing the code only to the parts that are affected (only the columns related to time), adding relevant samples (one row with and one without "customised date time") and expected output (what exactly you want to see in each case) compared to the currently received output. Multiple questions are always better than one huge question edited over an over, adding more and more things in a single thread. Also, please don't paste tables as pictures - even misaligned text is still more usable than well-aligned picture of text.